# How do I resolve "Cannot find module" when pointing to a branch?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, webpacker

I hope you guys are doing well.

So, the problem that I'm facing is that webpacker cannot find "[react-visual-filter](https://github.com/rfdavid/react-visual-filter)" module when I point to a branch.

Before, when everything was working fine, this package was pointing to a specific version:

```
"react-visual-filter": "^1.0.9"
```

So I created a simple PR([#5](https://github.com/rfdavid/react-visual-filter)) with improvement and I'm trying to test the result outside the module. To update the package.json file to point to my branch I used this command:

```
yarn add https://github.com/rfdavid/react-visual-filter.git#feature/add-text-box
```

And the package.json file got updated to:

```
"react-visual-filter": "https://github.com/rfdavid/react-visual-filter.git#feature/add-text-box"
```

Ok. I think everything is fine, but when webpacker try to compile the modifications this happens:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-visual-filter' in '/path/to/app/javascript/packs'
```

Not found?

I tried to delete the `node_modules` and install everything again with yarn, but no luck.

I can see that the react-visual-filter package was installed successfully inside the node_modules folder, but for some reason, it could not be found.

The funny thing is, after getting this error, if I try to update this:

```
import VisualFilter from "react-visual-filter";
```

To:

```
import VisualFilter from "react-visual-filter/src";
```

The module is found, but I face another problem:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (155:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Wait, what? So the package exist but it can be parsed?

But this file was being parsed just fine before. I'm not sure if this error is accurate. And I think I need to make this works this way:

```
import VisualFilter from "react-visual-filter";
```

I'm lost. If I return to "^1.0.9" the error disappears.

Probably something in my PR, but I can't see what.

I already updated yarn to `1.22.4`.

Did I miss something? Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up a simple react project with `create-react-app` and additionally installed `react-visual-filter` using link to github instead of version. I got the same error.

The content of `react-visual-filter` was missing `dist` folder with necessary files such as entrypoint `index.js`

The easiest workaround would be to unignore `dist` folder and push it to branch.

If you can't do that, you might exclude `src` `webpack.config.js` and other stuff from `.npmignore` and build it locally after installing

`cd node_modules/react-visual-filter`

`npm run build`

Comment: Thank you! I'll try both suggestions!

Comment: I could not get it working with npm run build, but you open my eyes about the dist folder and I can't thank you enough about that. After looking more closely at this site: https://r.cnpmjs.org/react-visual-filter, I tried to run `npm run transpile` inside node_modules/react-visual-filter and it worked like a charm.

Thank you!